# EF Core Migration with aspnetboilerplate Where to trigger context.Database.Migrate();

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need to ensure my application itself is able to upgrade his database model (apply migrations)

In the ABP architecture, where should I make the call to Migrate?

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

As this is a call to a infraestructure logic (Entity framework Core) it should be kept out from domain services and application services.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can execute database migrations in PostInitialize method in EntityFrameworkCoreModule.

```
 public class MyApplicationEntityFrameworkCoreModule : AbpModule
    {

        public override void PostInitialize()
        {
            if (!SkipDbSeed)
            {
                SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(IocManager);
            }

            // --> You can execute migrations here <--
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I try to resolve my DbContext here I got the following exception: `'BoilerplatePoc.EntityFrameworkCore.BoilerplatePocDbContext' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'`
What is wrong?
My example is based on this repo: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/0db208fa606784a6960da5cc90c63dc0f647126a/SimpleTaskSystem-Core/src

Comment: I get the same error when I try to do:

var context = IocManager.Resolve<MyDbContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();

Comment: @sroll @DennisÅhlin Resolve `IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>` and do `var context = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();`.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a working solution, for abp 4.3
This code allows your application to apply migrations at startup.

```
public override void PostInitialize()
{
    var dbContextProvider = IocManager.Resolve<IDbContextProvider<ExtranetDbContext>>();
    var unitOfWorkManager = IocManager.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>();

    using (var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        var context = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext(MultiTenancySides.Host);
        
        //Removes actual connection as it has been enlisted in a non needed transaction for migration
        context.Database.CloseConnection();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }

    if (!SkipDbSeed)
    {
        SeedHelper.SeedHostDb(IocManager);
    }
}
```

Details about the `IUnitOfWorkManager` can be found [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work).